# Run java file in inno setup

Tags: java, inno-setup

I have program in java who are copying some files to home java folders. In cmd it's work. I don't know how use it in Inno Setup.

I tried:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""cd {app}""/C ""java Javaxcomm"; Flags: runhidden waituntilterminated runascurrentuser
Filename: "java"; Parameters: "Javaxcomm"; WorkingDir: "{app}";  Flags: runhidden waituntilterminated runascurrentuser
Filename: "cmd"; Parameters: "/C java {app}\Javaxcomm"
```

Comment: Do you want to run Java code in order to copy files? Why don't you copy them with Inno Setup? Or do you want to copy a JAR file and a JRE? Please specify your question.

Comment: Flag in last line is that same how another lines.

Comment: Because i want find local java folde. with "java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home")". For example someone have someone have jre8, another person jre7. etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found another way. Maybe someone this will help. It isn't my code.

```
[Code]
var
  javaVersion: String;
  javaPath: String;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  if RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit', 'CurrentVersion') then
    begin
      RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit', 'CurrentVersion', javaVersion);
      MsgBox('Found Java Development Kit version ' + javaVersion, mbInformation, MB_OK);
      if RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\' + javaVersion, 'JavaHome') then
        begin
          RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\' + javaVersion, 'JavaHome', javaPath);
          MsgBox('Found Java Development Kit java_home: ' + javaPath, mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Result := True;
        end
      else
        begin
          MsgBox('Java Path not set for JDK' + javaVersion, mbInformation, MB_OK);
          MsgBox('RE-install java', mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Result := False;
        end
    end
  else if RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'CurrentVersion') then
    begin
      RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'CurrentVersion', javaVersion);
      MsgBox('Found Java Runtime Environment version ' + javaVersion, mbInformation, MB_OK);
      if RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\' + javaVersion, 'JavaHome') then
        begin
          RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\' + javaVersion, 'JavaHome', javaPath);
          MsgBox('Found Runtime Environment java_home: ' + javaPath, mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Result := True;
        end
      else
        begin
          MsgBox('Java Path not set for Java Runtime Environment' + javaVersion, mbInformation, MB_OK);
          MsgBox('RE-install java', mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Result := False;
        end
    end
  else
    begin
      MsgBox('v1 has not been found on your computer.'#13#13'Please Install it and try again.', MbError, Mb_Ok);
      Result := False;
    end
end;

function GetJAVAHome(S: String) : String;
begin
  Result := javaPath;
end;
Source: "{#MojaAppZrodla}\commapi\comm.jar"; DestDir: "{code:GetJAVAHome}\lib\ext"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "{#MojaAppZrodla}\commapi\win32com.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetJAVAHome}\bin"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "{#MojaAppZrodla}\commapi\javax.comm.properties"; DestDir: "{code:GetJAVAHome}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```